# iptables filter smtp?

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

I though I filtered out smtp on port 25 but when I run iptables -L to list active firewall rules, I get the following still in my result:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
```

should't that be removed, I have put the following rule in comments in my shell script, saved and reloaded iptables

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

UPDATE: 
the script I have used is here, only difference is that I commented out the port 25 lines http://linode.com/wiki/index.php/CentOS_IPTables_sh

Comment: I think we are going to need more information here.  You mention a shell script, does it completely flush all the rules?  We may need you to post more of the script, or possibly all of it.

Comment: I do this at the top:

# Wipe the tables clean
iptables -F

Comment: that's: iptables -F

Comment: +1 for posting the entire script (or, if it's long, putting it online and linking to it)

Comment: the script is here, only difference is that I commented out the port 25 lines http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/CentOS_IPTables_sh

Answer (score 1):

Just use Centos builtin iptables mechanisms they are better designed that using a script, it flushes rules, loads modules, checks syntax etc.

Comment: what mechanisms are you talking about then?

Comment: The init script and the iptables config file. /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config